# Delete duplicates between two sheets "Case Sensitive"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two sheets in excel and if vba found duplicates it will delete them.
I have searched for a while and finally I have find what I want here.
"[How do I delete duplicates between two excel sheets quickly vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665305/how-do-i-delete-duplicates-between-two-excel-sheets-quickly-vba)"

But in my case this didn't work for me. because this script consider that
abc and AbC are duplicates.
So is there anyway to modify the script so it will be case sensitive for all letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CompareMode of the dictionary. For detailed information have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a14xez73(v=vs.84).aspx

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' add this line:
dict.CompareMode = BinaryCompare
```

Comment: Are we talking about the code from accepted answer of Daniel Cook? Sub CleanDupes() ... from Dec 2 '12 at 1:55?

Comment: Ok, Now I am facing new problem.
after I have tried the new script with sample data It worked well.
but when I loaded my original data about 200000 at sheet1 and around 900000 at sheet2, it still runs till now and it seems it will take long time to finish.
Is there any way to make this process faster?

Comment: @user2132188 look towards `UsedRange` and `Application.ScreenUpdating` property.

Comment: Do you think that setting CompareMode to BinaryCompare made the code run slower? Did you check the speed with TextCompare as well?

Comment: @user2132188 it would be fair to accept this answer and submit a new question related performance: 900k rows for Excel is an extreme case by the way!

Comment: Do you think that setting CompareMode to BinaryCompare made the code run slower?
No I don't think though, I just ask if there is any way to make this process runs faster.
By the way it just took 15 minutes to finish. I am happy with this now.
I was afraid to take all over the night.
thanks for you all

Comment: I do not know which comparison would be quicker on scripting dictionaries. But you can try it and add comment with the results.

Comment: @user2132188: I'd recommend you place this issue as a new question (providing some source code) - this will increase your chances to solve the issue!