# Excel: Removing Duplicates Based On Case Sensitivity

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Thank you for reviewing my question.  Essentially I have a series of computer hostnames in column J.  In the world of host id's; "DFG, "dfg" and "dFg" are all unique.  Unfortunately, that's not how excel sees it.

I'm not too familiar with VBA however when I run a macro to and "remove duplicates" I get the following in VBA:

```
Columns("J:J").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("J:J").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

Is there anything I can add/substitute in the VBA code so that removing duplicates only removes *exact* duplicates and my 3 case sensitive host id'd remain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190031/how-to-delete-entire-row-when-case-sensitive-duplicates-are-found-in-excel-for

Comment: @TimWilliams - I'd lean towards closing as a duplicate. Thoughts?

Comment: Huh, I swear I searched the site (must not have used the correct terms) apologies for that.  If you'll allow me to review the link and see if there are any issues I would greatly appreciate it.  Otherwise please feel free to do as needed :-)

Comment: so I quickly read the link and there's still some confusion (please understand I'm very new to this as it's never been done in my department before)...

do I need to paste the entire code into the module?  or is there a piece of it that I need?  I'm not looking at 100k+ cells  column J would just have about <1000 unique host id names.

thanks again

Comment: @GilAraujo - I closed as duplicate because that link answers your question. If you have questions about how to implement that code after trying it out, post a new question with your specific problem. Please understand that I am not trying to be mean, but answering a bunch of questions in the comments section is not so much what SO is all about.