# VBA to remove all kinds of duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a excel file which needs to be unique, I want to remove the duplicates, all kinds of duplicates like below

[image]

Going to data->remove duplicates is not working.
i found a code, which is also not working

```
Sub SimpleExample()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3) , Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your data as a [markdown table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) rather than an image. A sample of the expected output would also be useful to clarify what you're trying to achieve. See [ask] for more details.

Comment: This post has some useful answers for this ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72748553/excel-remove-duplicates-based-on-2-columns-case-sensitive?rq=1

Comment: Just a FYI, but there is still human logic involved here. How do you expect Excel to know why to pick `United States` as the most correct version of what we as humans know as the USA? Same with any of the other values really. I think, maybe more feasible would be the top pick of all values that look similar instead.

Comment: Can there be also entries like `3 Country Germany` or `4 Country United States` or `3 Fruit apple`? Are those duplicates or not? Can there be digits? I guess the first step is that you precisely define what a duplicate is

Comment: Hi, the proper value United States(the value we get if we use =PROPER) alone must be present. It can contain digits, only the value columns must be unique, it can have 3 country united states, 4 country germany.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a more comprehensive example, one that includes the multiple variations of what you might encounter, as well as the desired output from that example. **Provide the example as Text which can be copy/pasted**, perhaps using this perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Advance filter [check this site](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-advanced-filter/)

[image: Excel Advanced Filter Data Tab]
[image: Excel Advanced Filter Dialog Box]

You can use VBA as well to manipulate Advance filter.

Add this function to a module

```
Function cleanVal(ByVal Val)
       Val = LCase(Trim(Val))
       Val = Replace(Val, "-", " ")
       Val = Replace(Val, ",", "")
       cleanVal = StrConv(Val, vbProperCase)
End Function
```

and in column next to table last column and cell value  "= cleanVal(C3)" and find the duplicates on new column , that should cover most of the variation .

Comment: This cannot resolve the user requirements fully. Please refer discussion below the question.