# Using VBA to remove row based on words listed in another sheet - slow performance

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a sheet (sheet1) with a large amount of data. This data has several columns, one of which is called nameColumn. nameColumn contains a single word per row.

In sheet 2, I have a list of 600 words.

I need to delete every row from sheet1 that contains a word in nameColumn that matches a word in sheet2

I've sorted sheet1 alphabetically by nameColumn, and have also sorted sheet2 alphabetically.

The code I've written works, but it is TERRIBLY. It creates a for loop for the number of rows in sheet 1, and a while loop nested inside which compares values between the two sheets and deletes the row if it finds a match in nameColumn. I tried "optimizing" it by telling the while loop to only increase the "i" if the word in question in sheet1 was alphabetically "greater" than that in sheet2.

This code takes 20 minutes to do just ~10k rows. How can I make it faster?

Note that I've tried changing the code to copy non-matching rows to another sheet, which appears to be just a slow. 
I've also looked at this post [Excel / VBA Remove duplicate rows by cross referencing 2 different sheets then deleting 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419573/excel-vba-remove-duplicate-rows-by-cross-referencing-2-different-sheets-then-d), and frankly, I don't understand enough of it to try to implement it.

```
Sub removerows3()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim numberof_data_rows As Long
numberof_data_rows = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim numberof_alert_rows As Long
numberof_alert_rows = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim nameColumn As Integer
nameColumn = 3 

Dim current_alert_row As Integer
current_alert_row = 2

Dim current_data_row As Long
current_data_row = 2

Dim keep_searching_dosealert As Integer
keep_searching_dosealert = 1


For current_data_row = 2 To numberof_data_rows


Do While keep_searching_dosealert = 1
    If Sheet2.Cells(current_alert_row, 1) = Cells(current_data_row, nameColumn) 
        Cells(current_data_row, nameColumn).EntireRow.Delete
        keep_searching_dosealert = 0
        current_data_row = current_data_row - 1
        numberof_data_rows = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ElseIf StrComp(Sheet2.Cells(current_alert_row, 1), Sheet1.Cells(current_data_row, nameColumn)) = 1 Then 
        keep_searching_dosealert = 0
        current_alert_row = current_alert_row - 1

    ElseIf StrComp(Sheet2.Cells(current_alert_row, 1), Sheet1.Cells(current_data_row, nameColumn)) = -1 Then 
        keep_searching_dosealert = 1
        current_alert_row = current_alert_row + 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("error")

    End If
Loop
keep_searching_dosealert = 1


Next current_data_row

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that doing matches of the name column on the sheet2 words column (using match or vlookup), then setting an autofilter on sheet1, filtering out the rows you don't want using the lookup results, and then copy the filtered set to a new sheet would be quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the following code. It creates a temporary array-formula in a column to the right of Sheet1. It's 20 columns to the right of the column we are checking - increase this number if necessary.

```
Sub DeleteAcross2()
    Dim calc As Variant
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim dels As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rngDel As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'remember the Calculation Mode to reinstate later
    calc = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B2:B70")      'change this range
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:A4")       'change this range

    'add a formula-column 20 columns to the right - increase this number if necessary
    rng1.Offset(0, 20).FormulaArray = "=ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$70,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,0))"
    'creates a column of True/False values - we will delete rows with False
    dels = rng1.Offset(0, 20).Value
    For x = 1 To UBound(dels, 1)
        If dels(x, 1) = False Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = rng1.Cells(x, 1)       'the first cell
            Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, rng1.Cells(x, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next x
    rng1.Offset(0, 20).Clear        'remove the array-formula (required)
    If rngDel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub      'no matches found
    rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.Calculation = calc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It won't take 20 minutes to run :)

Comment: +1 for use of Union to do bulk row delete. Would suggest dim'ing x as Long to allow handling of larger data ranges.

Comment: @chuff Thank you. Yes, I normally (always) use Long for rows.

Comment: In case there is nothing to delete, it exits macro without setting `Calculation` and `ScreenUpdating` back to previous values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the rows of Sheet1 data with matching words, the code below creates a new copy of the data -- excluding the rows with matching words -- in Sheet3. The next steps would be to delete Sheet1 and rename and move Sheet3 (I have not included those steps in the code).

The code copies the nameColumn in Sheet1 and the wordColumn in Sheet2 into VBA arrays. It loops through the nameColumn array searching for matches in the wordColumn array. To speed up the matching process, the word list in Sheet2 is sorted prior to matching. When a match is found, a flag value of 1 is set in the result array.

It then writes the result array back to Sheet1 and sets an autofilter on the Sheet1 data range to exclude rows with matched words. The last step is copying the filtered data to Sheet3.

I tested the code on a 42,000-word nameColumn with 26 columns of random numeric data, matched against a sorted 600-word list randomly drawn from the nameColumn words. The code took about 5 seconds to run, with 80 percent of that time spent in the word match loop. (I also tested a version of the code that deleted the matched rows in place, a change which doubled the execution time.)

```vb
Sub FilterOnNoMatchAndCopy()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LastCell As Range, ws2LastCell As Range
    Dim valueArr(), searchArr(), resultArr()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sort_Sheet2_list As Boolean

    sort_Sheet2_list = True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'   create Sheet3 if it doesn't exist, clear it if it does
    Set ws3 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws3 Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=ws2).Name = "Sheet3"
        Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    End If
    ws3.Cells.Clear

'   Find last cell in used ranges
    With ws1
        Set ws1LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row, _
            .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Column)
    End With
    With ws2
        Set ws2LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row, _
            .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Column)
    End With

'   copy the nameColumn and wordColumn into VBA arrays 
'   (if nameColumn and wordColumn are not in column A, change here)     
    valueArr = ws1.Range("$A$2:$A$" & ws1LastCell.Row)
    If sort_Sheet2_list Then
        ws2.Range("$A$2:$A$" & ws2LastCell.Row).Sort Key1:=ws2.Range("A2"), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End If
    searchArr = ws2.Range("$A$2:$A$" & ws2LastCell.Row)

'   create a new array that will flag which words in nameColumn are matches
    ReDim resultArr(LBound(valueArr, 1) To UBound(valueArr, 1), 1 To 1)

'  search for matches 
   For i = 1 To UBound(valueArr, 1)
        j = 1
        Do While j < (UBound(searchArr, 1) + 1)
            If valueArr(i, 1) > searchArr(j, 1) Then
                j = j + 1
            Else
                If valueArr(i, 1) = searchArr(j, 1) Then
                    resultArr(i, 1) = 1
                End If
                j = UBound(searchArr, 1) + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next

'   write match results to Sheet1, set autofilter to exclude matches, 
'       and copy result to Sheet3
    With ws1
        .Cells(1, ws1LastCell.Column + 1).value = "found"
        .Range(.Cells(2, ws1LastCell.Column + 1), _
            .Cells(ws1LastCell.Row, ws1LastCell.Column + 1)) = _
            resultArr
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter ws1LastCell.Column + 1, "<>1"
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(ws1LastCell.Row, ws1LastCell.Column)).Copy Destination:=ws3.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Cells(1, ws1LastCell.Column + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```